# Does Yama, the son of Sun god is the first human died?

Tags: vedas, yama

[This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yama) tells that According to the Vedas, Yama is said to have been the first mortal who died. Which scriptures from Vedas mentions the same?

Answer (score 1):

According the link: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10014.htm , it is mentioned in the Rig-HYMN XIV.

> 1. HONOUR the King with thine oblations, Yama, Vivasvān's Son, who gathers men together,
>      Who travelled to the lofty heights above us, who searches out and shows the path to many.
>      2 **Yama first found for us a place to dwell in: this pasture never can be taken from
>      Us.**
>      Men born on earth tread their own paths that lead them whither our ancient Fathers have departed.

The above is also supported by the evidence given in the sanskrit dictionary:  [http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=यम&lang=sans&action=Search](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%AE&lang=sans&action=Search)